# Determining if a Linear Transformation is Surjective

Tags: linear-algebra

I am aware that to check if a linear transformation is injective, then we must simply check if the kernel of that linear transformation is the zero subspace or not. If the kernel is the zero subspace, then the linear transformation is indeed injective.

Is there a similar way to check for surjectivity?

Comment: I think the best way to think about this question is if you have a context. Are you studying linear transformations represented by matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $T : V \rightarrow W$ be a linear map and $T^* : W^* \rightarrow V^*$ the map induced on the dual space. Then $T$ is surjective if and only if $T^*$ is injective if and only if the kernel of $T^*$ is the zero subspace.

I think that's about as similar as you can get.

Comment: What is the dual space?

Comment: Also are $T^{*},W^{*},V^{*}$ arbitrary vector spaces or does the asterisk mean something in linear algebra?

Comment: Given any (real) vector space $V$, one can define $V^* = \{f : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R} | f \text{ a linear transformation}\}$. This is called the dual space because one can prove that when $V$ is finite dimensional, there is a natural isomorphism $V \cong (V^*)^*$.

If one has a map $T : V \rightarrow W$, then one can define $T^* : W^* \rightarrow V^*$ as follows. I need to take a map $f : W \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and define a map $V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. There is only one sensible way to do this: $f \circ T$. It would be a good exercise to now check my claim above.

Comment: Ah, I haven't learned that yet, but sounds interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a linear transformation $T \in L(V,W)$ is surjective iff $\text{range} (T) = W$. For finite dimensional spaces, another necessary and sufficient condition is that the dimension of range$(T)=\dim (W)$.

Comment: What does $L(V,W)$ mean?

Comment: $L(V,W)$ is the space of all linear maps from vector space $V$ to vector space $W$.

Comment: If the spaces involved are not finite-dimensional, this fails. The OP is probably studying finite-dim spaces, but some caution to state hypotheses explicitly isn't unwarranted.

Comment: Good point. The edited criterium is the proper one, and I should modify my post accordingly.